# Negating and combining multiple regex statements into one

Tags: regex

I have this regex that [matches all excluded UK postcodes](https://regex101.com/r/dQ7wV3/5)

```
^((AB)([15][0-6]|[24][1-5]|[3][0-9])|(BT)([1][1-79]?|[2346][0-9]?|[5][1-8]?|[7][014-9]?|[8][0-2]?|[9][2-4]?)|(DD)([1][01]?|[2-9])|(DG)([1][0-46]?|[2-9])|(EH)([1234][0-9]?|[5][1-5]?|[6-8]|[9][59]?)|(FK)([1][0-9]?|[2][0-2]?|[3-9])|(GY)([1-9])|(G)([1][1-5]?|[2][0-3]?|[3][1-4]?|[4][0-6]?|[5][1-38]?|[67][0-9]|[8][0-4]|[9])|(HS)[1-9]|(IM)([1-7]|[8][6]?|[9][9]?)|(IV)([14][0-9]|[2][0-8]|[3][0-26]|[5][1-6]|[6-9])|(JE)[1-4]|(KA)([12][0-9]?|[3][0]?|[4-9])|(KW)([1][0-7]?|[2-9])|(KY)([1][0-6]?|[2-8]|[9][9]?)|(ML)([1][0-2]?|[2-9])|(PA)([1246][0-9]?|[37][0-8]?|[589])|(PH)([1][0-8]?|[2][6]?|[3][16]?|[4][249]?|[5-9])|(TD)([1][0-13-4]?|[2-9])|(ZE)[1-3])
```

that I need to combine with this regex that does check if postcode format is correct.

```
^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$
```

Problem I ran into is making negation out of first post code - if I try to wrap it in `[^()]` regex blows up

**How would I go around negating first one and combining it with second one as one regex?**

**UPDATE:**

I have followed @georg 's suggestion and failed somewhere.

[It matches on excluded codes](https://regex101.com/r/nI0mY0/5)

```
^(?!((AB|ab)([15][0-6]|[24][1-5]|[3][0-9])|(BT|bt)([1][1-79]?|[2346][0-9]?|[5][1-8]?|[7][014-9]?|[8][0-2]?|[9][2-4]?)|(DD|dd)([1][01]?|[2-9])|(DG|dg)([1][0-46]?|[2-9])|(EH|eh)([1234][0-9]?|[5][1-5]?|[6-8]|[9][59]?)|(FK|fk)([1][0-9]?|[2][0-2]?|[3-9])|(GY|gy)([1-9])|(G|g)([1][1-5]?|[2][0-3]?|[3][1-4]?|[4][0-6]?|[5][1-38]?|[67][0-9]|[8][0-4]|[9])|(HS|hs)[1-9]|(IM|im)([1-7]|[8][6]?|[9][9]?)|(IV|iv)([14][0-9]|[2][0-8]|[3][0-26]|[5][1-6]|[6-9])|(JE|je)[1-4]|(KA|ka)([12][0-9]?|[3][0]?|[4-9])|(KW|kw)([1][0-7]?|[2-9])|(KY|ky)([1][0-6]?|[2-8]|[9][9]?)|(ML|ml)([1][0-2]?|[2-9])|(PA|pa)([1246][0-9]?|[37][0-8]?|[589])|(PH|ph)([1][0-8]?|[2][6]?|[3][16]?|[4][249]?|[5-9])|(TD|td)([1][0-13-4]?|[2-9])|(ZE|ze)[1-3]) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2}$)([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$
```

Comment: The basic pattern is `^(?! invalid $) valid $`.

Comment: Another thing to consider: The first regex only matches uppercase letters, the second one also matches lowercase. You should decide on one or the other. Which do you prefer?

Comment: @georg doesn't seem to fly, https://regex101.com/r/nI0mY0/2 I have gone somewhere wrong - it matches on excluded postcodes.

Comment: @LIUFA: I don't have enough courage to debug it ;) but are you sure you still want a regex for this? Even if you get it working at some point, it will remain unreadable and fragile. Have you considered a step-by-step solution ([the rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Formatting) seem to be pretty straighforward)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATM I feel like a champion!

[This does it](https://regex101.com/r/nI0mY0/6):

```
^(?!((AB|ab)([15][0-6]|[24][1-5]|[3][0-9])|(BT|bt)([1][1-79]?|[2346][0-9]?|[5][1-8]?|[7][014-9]?|[8][0-2]?|[9][2-4]?)|(DD|dd)([1][01]?|[2-9])|(DG|dg)([1][0-46]?|[2-9])|(EH|eh)([1234][0-9]?|[5][1-5]?|[6-8]|[9][59]?)|(FK|fk)([1][0-9]?|[2][0-2]?|[3-9])|(GY|gy)([1-9])|(G|g)([1][1-5]?|[2][0-3]?|[3][1-4]?|[4][0-6]?|[5][1-38]?|[67][0-9]|[8][0-4]|[9])|(HS|hs)[1-9]|(IM|im)([1-7]|[8][6]?|[9][9]?)|(IV|iv)([14][0-9]|[2][0-8]|[3][0-26]|[5][1-6]|[6-9])|(JE|je)[1-4]|(KA|ka)([12][0-9]?|[3][0]?|[4-9])|(KW|kw)([1][0-7]?|[2-9])|(KY|ky)([1][0-6]?|[2-8]|[9][9]?)|(ML|ml)([1][0-2]?|[2-9])|(PA|pa)([1246][0-9]?|[37][0-8]?|[589])|(PH|ph)([1][0-8]?|[2][6]?|[3][16]?|[4][249]?|[5-9])|(TD|td)([1][0-13-4]?|[2-9])|(ZE|ze)[1-3]))^(([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$)
```